# Removing font warning

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, warnings

Given this simple LaTeX code

```
\documentclass [spanish] {book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Hola}
\end{document}
```

I get the warning `` Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined(Font) using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead` ``

I'm writing in spanish and using lots of TikZ, so I have to be careful not to spoil the pictures. How do I get rid of it? What am I doing wrong with fonts?

Comment: Your document or class wants to use small caps, but your font doesn't have any. It should be safe to ignore this warning, LaTeX automatically uses the regular font.

Comment: The example doesn't produce the warning.

Comment: To be more precise, somewhere you're trying to use **bold** (extended) small caps, which aren't available in `lmodern`. Either pick another font which has them (e.g., `kpfonts` does), or stick with `lmodern` and use the automatic substitution to use normal bold (extended) instead.

Comment: @egreg I do have it. I think it is because the format tries to use bold small caps for the index roman numeral...

Comment: @egreg you need to compile twice to get the bold roman numeral in the toc.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, yes, indeed! The horrible small caps Roman numerals.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! Mystery solved! The problem was in the fake the small caps bold roman numerals displayed in the table of contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A warning is unavoidable, unless much lower level code is used.

The issue is that `babel-spanish`, by default, wants to use small caps Roman numerals instead of lowercase ones like in English.

However the Latin Modern fonts, contrary to European Modern (the default for the T1 encoding) don't have a boldface small caps font. Thus `babel-spanish` uses a trick: it fakes the font by using capital letters from the normal boldface font, but at a reduced size (the size corresponding to subscripts).

You have three strategies. The first two strategies require some code to add before `\begin{document}`.

#### Strategy 1

Substitute the Latin Modern nonexistent font with the corresponding one in European Modern.

```
\sbox0{%
  \fontseries{bx}\scshape
  \global\expandafter\let\csname T1/lmr/bx/sc/10\expandafter\endcsname\the\font
}
```

Disadvantage: you need to do this for every font size you need. For the TOC, which is the real problem, just `10` is needed (or `10.95` with the `11pt` option, or `12` for the `12pt` option).

#### Strategy 2

Since you *know* that the faked small caps Roman numerals will be used, avoid the checking business that just produce the annoying warnings.

```
\makeatletter
%% lmodern has no boldface small caps and we know it
%% so we avoid all the warnings related to the faking business
\def\es@xlsc#1#2#3{%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont#1{#3}}%
}
\makeatother
```

#### Strategy 3

Use uppercase Roman numerals.

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-ucroman]{babel}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @Skillmon said, the "problem" is that somewhere you are trying to use a font that the `lmodern` suite does not have (something bold in a part title maybe? I do not know), so a substitution is done.

If you are happy with the substitution, you can just hide the warning under the carpet. Given that the warning(s) are:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/lmr/bx/n' instead on input line 2.


Package spanish Warning: Replacing `T1/lmr/bx/sc' by 
(spanish)                faked small caps on input line 2.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

you can use this *before* your `\documentclass`:

```
\RequirePackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Font shape `T1/lmr/bx/sc'}
\WarningFilter{spanish}{Replacing `T1/lmr/bx/sc'}
% I normally leave that last one alone, as a reminder I am shoving
% things under the carpet, but well...
\WarningFilter{latexfont}{Some font shapes were}
```

...and hala, no warnings ;-)

(This is cheating, though, so use it sparingly and only if you are sure about it).

On a side note, PGF-Ti*k*z has nothing to do with this!

Comment: Oh, no, not `silence`, please ;-)